# Can I use an existing local repository in DataGrip?

Tags: git, datagrip

I've looked through the following links for a way to link an existing local repository with DataGrip:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/06/01/tutorial-how-to-use-git-with-datagrip/

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/importing-a-local-directory-to-subversion-repository.html

It seems like the expected workflow is to clone the remote repository using DataGrip's git clone equivalent in the GUI. However I am trying to use an existing repository on my local machine with the Git function.

I was able to add a different repository to DataGrip by deleting the existing local repository and re-cloning using DataGrip's tool. I'm reluctant to do that now because there was some other environment and authentication setup with this repository that I'd rather avoid re-doing.

Does anyone know how to use a local repository with DataGrip's Git integration, without deleting the repository first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to associate a directory with a version control system﻿.

Follow instructions described in [enabling version control article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html#associate_directory_with_VCS)
[image: version control dir mapping]

Comment: Got it! That's what I was missing. Thank you.